# SSL problems in ruby but not curl

Tags: ruby, curl, ssl

I have the following working curl command:

```
curl -k -E some_cert.pem https://someurl.com/__dirlist__
```

Trying to implement this in Ruby I have:

```
uri = URI.parse('https://someurl.com/__dirlist__')

http_session = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http_session.ca_file = "some_cert.pem"
http_session.use_ssl = true
http_session.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

res = http_session.get(uri.request_uri)
```

I've played around with using all the different versions of SSL (using `http_session.ssl_version = :SSLv2_client` etc), all which failed (some with different messages), I matched up versions using wireshark to see what curl was using so don't think that's the problem (although ruby was sending a bunch of extra settings none seemed pertinent).

From reading other bug reports I've seen people have a lot of problems related to not having the appropriate certificates in their cert store however with `SSL::VERIFY_NONE` I don't see how that could matter.

I can't rule out that it could be the openssl baked into my Ruby but it seems unlikely to me given I've also run this code on another machine and gotten the same error and I would assume curl is linking against the same openssl (I don't know how to check this).

I've looked through the rdocs like I've exhausted all the settings available in Net:HTTP.

This is the nondescript error that I'm seeing (anonymised slightly):

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_read:: ssl handshake failure
from /Users/a_user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@project/gems/right_http_connection-1.3.0/lib/net_fix.rb:52:in `sysread'
from /Users/a_user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@project/gems/right_http_connection-1.3.0/lib/net_fix.rb:52:in `block in rbuf_fill'
from /Users/a_user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:68:in `timeout'
from /Users/a_user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:99:in `timeout'
from /Users/a_user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@project/gems/right_http_connection-1.3.0/lib/net_fix.rb:51:in `rbuf_fill'
from /Users/a_user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:122:in `readuntil'
from /Users/a_user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:132:in `readline'
from /Users/a_user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2562:in `read_status_line'
from /Users/a_user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2551:in `read_new'
from /Users/a_user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@project/gems/right_http_connection-1.3.0/lib/net_fix.rb:146:in `request'
from /Users/a_user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@project/gems/right_http_connection-1.3.0/lib/net_fix.rb:131:in `block in request'
from /Users/a_user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:745:in `start'
from /Users/a_user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@project/gems/right_http_connection-1.3.0/lib/net_fix.rb:129:in `request'
from /Users/a_user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1026:in `get'
```

Comment: You may need to recompile your `rvm` built Ruby to be sure it has the OpenSSL library bundled in correctly. Try building `1.9.3-p448` and see if you still have the issue. `-p0` is really out of date.

Comment: Look into the [Curb](https://github.com/taf2/curb) gem. It uses cURL under the covers so if it works with cURL it'll work with Curb, and Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

From the curl manual:

```
   -k, --insecure
          (SSL)  This  option explicitly allows curl to perform "insecure"
          SSL connections and transfers. All SSL connections are attempted
          to  be  made secure by using the CA certificate bundle installed
          by default. This makes  all  connections  considered  "insecure"
          fail unless -k, --insecure is used.
```

So running without `-k` might reveal the problem on curl as well.

Comment: Ah, I copied the curl command from a shell script and when I looked up the -k flag I assumed that was essentially the same as `SSL:VERIFY_NONE`. Clearly I was mistaken, the curl command runs fine without the -k flag.